# How can I include icons in Mermaid.js diagrams in Material for MkDocs?

Tags: mermaid, mkdocs-material

Using the [Mermaid.js live editor](https://mermaid.live/), I can create a simple diagram like this:

```
flowchart LR
    A[fas:fa-tree A] --> B(far:fa-gem B)
```

Which is displayed as:

[image]

However, when I copy this to my website which uses [Material for MkDocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/), the same code is displayed without the icons, as:

[image: diagram2]

I have the [Mermaid](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/extensions/python-markdown-extensions/#superfences) and [Emoji](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/emoji/) Markdown extension set up, and I am able to display other icons on the same page (not in a diagram), such as `:smile:` and `:material-server:`. I even downloaded the [free Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/download) icons and can display them as described in [Using Local Custom Icons](https://github.com/facelessuser/mkdocs-material-extensions/#using-local-custom-icons), e.g. `:fa-regular-moon:`. However, *none* of these show up when used within the Mermaid diagram.

Mermaid 10.1 intruduced [Markdown formatting](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#markdown-formatting), which may permit icons too, but the latest Material for MkDocs is 9.4.8, which only includes Mermaid.js 9.4.3 ([source](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/changelog/)).

These are pages which seemed applicable but did not lead to a working solution for me:

- [Font Awesome icons not loading #27](https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin/issues/27)
- [How to allow font awesome icons in mermaid diagrams? #5140](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/discussions/5140)
- [material 5.x does not render Font Awesome icons in mermaid diagrams](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/1698)
- [Advanced Mermaid Notes](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extras/mermaid/)

**How can I include icons in Mermaid.js diagrams in Material for MkDocs?**

Answer (score 3):

A co-worker suggested the following, which is basically using an in-line HTML img tag to pull in the icon image, saved to the project's images folder.

```
 flowchart LR
     A["Here is how an image is done in mkdocs mermaid diagrams"]
     A --> B[<img src='images/box.png' width='25' height='25' /> This is a box]
```

So I have been going to the font sites, downloading the icons as .svg files and adding them in that way.

Comment: Thank you.  It's not simple or pretty, but it works. BTW, you can get 2025 .svg files in one .zip [from Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/download).

Comment: Thanks. Good tip on the zip download. Best of luck.

Comment: same technique for SD not work...